# What is the name of Yoga Nidra Wakeup Conch?

Tags: vishnu, devi, shaktism

Wondering, if anybody knows the name of the Conch that Uma blows to wake Vishnu from Yoga Nidra? There is a particular conch for that I have heard.

Comment: Vishnu and Durga (Yodanidra) are the same in essence.So their conchs i think are the same.So far as I know, 'PAnchajanya' is the conch of Sri Vishnu.

Comment: Only when the form of Mahalakshmi was taken by Devi to kill Mahishasura, Varun gave Her a conch as per Sri Sri Devi-Mahatmya